# 'super' outside of function or class

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I can't transpile this little piece of code:

```
class FooBar extends SomeParent {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  start() {
    var foo = function() {
      super.start();     // <-- Error: 'super' outside of function or class
    };
  } 
}
```

The error thrown is `'super' outside of function or class` .

However, the same code transpiles fine in [Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/).

I'm transpiling using a custom Node.JS program using this command:

```
babel.transformFileSync(filename,  { presets: [ 'es2015' ] } );
```

Installation info:

```
$ npm ls --global --depth 0
/usr/lib
├── babel@6.3.13
├── babel-core@6.3.17
├── babel-plugin-external-helpers-2@6.3.13
├── babel-plugin-syntax-async-functions@6.3.13
├── babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator@6.3.13
├── babel-plugin-transform-regenerator@6.3.18
├── babel-plugin-transform-runtime@6.3.13
├── babel-polyfill@6.3.14
├── babel-preset-es2015@6.3.13
└── npm@1.4.28

$ node -v
v0.10.40
```

What am I doing wrong? I had no problems when transpiling using Babel 5...

Comment: Could be that the REPL uses babel 5 and you are using babel 6?

Comment: Use an arrow function instead of a regular function, that will ensure the `super` is from the parent scope. I'm not sure exactly which implementation is correct, but I would *guess* Babel 6 as it doesn't make sense to access `super` outside of the class

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: @RGraham: indeed, ussing an arrow function solves the problem. Thanks. Using a function *does* make sense to me, just as an arrow function makes sense. I posted just a test case, but the real code with the described problem comes from an era when there didn't exist any arrow function. Whatever, I prefer the arrow variant too. I'd like to accept this as an answer, though.

Comment: I refrained from leaving an answer because I'm unclear as to whether or not the behaviour of v6 is expected. The reason I said *made sense* is because the *context* of a function could be changed. The context of an arrow cannot. Therefore, it will always tie together `this` and `super` unlike a function where `this` can be modified

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It works in the Babel REPL because Babel 5 did not have checks for this I'd assume.

This is not valid:

```
class Example extends Parent {
  start() {
    var foo = function() {
      super.start();
    };
  }
}
```

But using an arrow function does:

```
class Example extends Parent {
  start() {
    var foo = () => {
      super.start();
    };
  }
}
```

because `super` behavior is based on the `this` environment of its calling location. While an arrow function shares its `this` environment with its parent, a standard function introduces a whole not `this` environment.

Specifically:

1. [12.3.5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-super-keyword-runtime-semantics-evaluation) calls `MakeSuperPropertyReference()`
2. [12.3.5.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-makesuperpropertyreference) calls `GetThisEnvironment()` which in the first case will be the function expression, and in the arrow case will be the class method, and then calls `HasSuperBinding()` in that environment.
3. [8.1.1.3.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-makesuperpropertyreference) will return `false` in the first case because function expressions do not have a `[[HomeObject]]` whereas class methods do.